# Do I need to install Japanese TrueType font, Ume-font

Tags: 10.10, package-management, dependencies, updates

I have an English Ubuntu. Today suddenly the update manager asks me to download 48 MB of "Japanese TrueType font, Ume-font". It says it is a new install. Do I really need this for something? I can not imagine why I need Japanese fonts.

This is the package that I am being 'forced' to install: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/fonts/ttf-umefont

It is listed under DISTRIBUTION UPDATES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed wine, and this "update" no more popped up.

Comment: I now found it indeed! http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/wine1.2 Why a Japanese font package is marked as "Recommended" for Wine is beyond me (especially given its large size), but well, that is something that most likely has a good reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find that package in the [official package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com), I'll assume it comes from a third-party repository.

To find out which package depends on ume-font, install apt-rdepends ([instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-check-package-dependencies-with-apt-rdepends-on-ubuntu.html)) and do a reverse lookup ([info](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/aptrdependsmanpage.htm)):

```
apt-rdepends -r ume-font
```

Comment: It does come from the official package list, the name is ttf-umefont: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/fonts/ttf-umefont -- I still do not understand WHY it is being installed...?